# In Hadoop, How will Namenode get the rack details and the datanode belonging to a rack?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Assume in a Hadoop cluster we have 2 racks rck1 and rck2. Each rack has 5 nodes. How will the Namenode come to know that node 1 belongs to rack 1, node 3 belongs to rack 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must configure the system to specify how the rack information is determined. For example, [this Cloudera link](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cm_mc_specify_rack.html) tells you how to configure the racks for hosts in Cloudera Manager.

Alternatively, [this Apache link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/RackAwareness.html) explains how this information can be specified in an external script of java class via configuration files.

The topology is typically of the form /myrack/myhost, although you can use a deeper hierarchy. They have the following example in python which assumes a /24 subnet for each rack, and hence extracts the first three bytes of the IP address to use as a rack number - you could adopt a similar approach if you can set the node IP addresses accordingly, or write your own script to determine rack from IP address or other available information on each node (even a simple hard-coded mapping between e.g. hostname and rack would work in your example with relatively few nodes).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# this script makes assumptions about the physical environment.
#  1) each rack is its own layer 3 network with a /24 subnet, which
# could be typical where each rack has its own
#     switch with uplinks to a central core router.
#
#             +-----------+
#             |core router|
#             +-----------+
#            /             \
#   +-----------+        +-----------+
#   |rack switch|        |rack switch|
#   +-----------+        +-----------+
#   | data node |        | data node |
#   +-----------+        +-----------+
#   | data node |        | data node |
#   +-----------+        +-----------+
#
# 2) topology script gets list of IP's as input, calculates network address, and prints '/network_address/ip'.

import netaddr
import sys
sys.argv.pop(0)                                                  # discard name of topology script from argv list as we just want IP addresses

netmask = '255.255.255.0'                                        # set netmask to what's being used in your environment.  The example uses a /24

for ip in sys.argv:                                              # loop over list of datanode IP's
address = '{0}/{1}'.format(ip, netmask)                      # format address string so it looks like 'ip/netmask' to make netaddr work
try:
   network_address = netaddr.IPNetwork(address).network     # calculate and print network address
   print "/{0}".format(network_address)
except:
   print "/rack-unknown"                                    # print catch-all value if unable to calculate network address
```